# Run same effect in multi id's in the same page

Tags: jquery, html

I need to run same effect in multi id's in the same page
What is the short way to do this:

```
function showDisc1(){$('#bottomBox1').slideDown();$("#bottomBox1").addClass("open");$("#bottomBox1").removeClass("close");}
function showDisc2(){$('#bottomBox2').slideDown();$("#bottomBox2").addClass("open");$("#bottomBox2").removeClass("close");}
function showDisc3(){$('#bottomBox3').slideDown();$("#bottomBox3").addClass("open");$("#bottomBox3").removeClass("close");}
function showDisc4(){$('#bottomBox4').slideDown();$("#bottomBox4").addClass("open");$("#bottomBox4").removeClass("close");}
...... etc

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#openbottomBox1').click(function(){
if ( $('#bottomBox1').hasClass('close') ) {
showDisc1();
} else if ( $('#bottomBox1').hasClass('open') ) {
hideDisc1();
};});});
.... again!!
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bottomBox close">
<div class="wrapper">
<a class="left disc" href="javascript:;" id="openbottomBox1"><div class="left text">View Description</div><div class="sprite right"></div></a> | <a class="itemDetails" href="javascript:;" id="itemDetails1">Details</a>
</div>
<p class="close clear discContent" id="bottomBox1"><a href="javascript:;" class="hideDisc" id="hideDisc1">x</a>
jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the HTML structure as well.

Comment: Is your intent to run the operation on a single element at a time or all elements at once and everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other choice but to use IDs as identifiers, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#openbottomBox1, #openbottomBox2, #openbottomBox3, #openbottomBox4').click(function()
    {
        var $bottomBox = $('#bottomBox' + this.id.substr(-1));

        if ( $bottomBox.hasClass('close') )
        {
            $bottomBox.slideDown().addClass('open').removeClass('close');
        }
        else if ( $bottomBox.hasClass('open') )
        {
            $bottomBox.slideUp().removeClass('open').addClass('close');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You could replace the `if ... hasClass()` part with `$bottomBox.slideToggle().toggleClass('open close');` or even `$bottomBox.slideToggle(1000, function() { $(this).toggleClass('open close'); });`

Comment: @Stefan - Since I don't know what else the OP has got going on there in his page, I opted for this solution, which is more explicit. Your solution is terser, and would generally be preferred.

Comment: I understand that, just wanted to add that for the OP and everyone else. You came up ith a great work around though! :)

Answer (score 2):

Give all these boxes a single class name, and bind the click to the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.box').click(function(){
       toggleDisc(this);
   });
});

function toggleDisc(that){
   if ($(that).hasClass('close'){
       $(that).slideDown().addClass("open").removeClass("close");
   }else{
       // the other thing
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class (in this example "bottomboxes") to all the elements and use a class selector to do the operation.

```
function toggleDiscs(
{   
  $('.bottomboxes').slideToggle();
}
```

Finally, you might consider using SlideToggle instead of slideDown and slideUp so you don't have to keep track of whether it is open. (also shown)

Also, it is more efficient to use chaining to do multiple operations on the same element instead of repeatedly selecting it.

So instead of

```
   $("#something").doSomething;
   $("#something").doSomethingElse;
```

Do this

```
   $("#something").doSomething.doSomethingElse;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a multicall function that does hide and show based on the variables passed like so:

```
function ShowHide(element,action){  
   if(action == 'show'){
        $(element).slideDown();
        $(element).addClass("open");
        $(element).removeClass("close");
    }else{
        //Do hiding functions here;
    }

}
```

then in your document ready you pass a string of the element you want changed with the action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#openbottomBox1').click(function(){
if ( $('#bottomBox1').hasClass('close') ) {
ShowHide('#bottomBox1','show');
} else if ( $('#bottomBox1').hasClass('open') ) {
ShowHide('#bottomBox1','hide');
};});});
```

Comment: `$('#bottomBox1').slideToggle().toggleClass('open close');` could also work :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of jQuerys chainability.

```
$('#bottomBox4').slideDown();$("#bottomBox4").addClass("open");$("#bottomBox4").removeClass("close");
```

can be replaced with;

```
$('#bottomBox4').slideDown().addClass("open").removeClass("close");
```

Comment: only makes the lines shorter doesnt really make use of javascript functions